# Mercado Pago Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mercadopago, mercadopagosdk

I am trying to integrate Mercado Pago into my ASP.NetCore Application. However, when I call save method, I am receiving the message

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpRuntime' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For [Mercado Pago SDK for .Net](https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-dotnet), it does not support `.net core`. Check [Error de runtime con Net Core 2.0 #72](https://github.com/mercadopago/dx-dotnet/issues/72) and try the [Unofficial Mercado Pago SDK for .NET](https://github.com/LeximSoluciones/Lexim-MercadoPago-Sdk) from the comment suggestion.